# Google Streetview Android / iOS SDK vs indoor panorama

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-street-view

Anyone having luck with Google Streetview SDK for Android or iOS and indoor panorama as default position of camera? If i supply lat long position that corresponds to indoor, i see either nothing, or i am placed on the street nearby. Unlike with Google Streetview JS SDK where the indoor streetview seems to work.

On Android i was working with 9.0.1 services version, then i tried the 10.2 as shown below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
```

What is interesting that when the streetview is opened i am able to get into building by traveling on the street, but i am not able to set the inital location in building by calling panorama.setPosition() unlike with JS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution - setPosition with panoId identifier. You can get the panoId by watching the onStreetViewPanoramaChange listener while manually traveling the camera inside of building in openened Streetview.